# Basic Game Loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement the last game loop on [this site](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/)

Here is the code from the website:

```
const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5;

DWORD next_game_tick = GetTickCount();
int loops;
float interpolation;

bool game_is_running = true;
while( game_is_running ) {

    loops = 0;
    while( GetTickCount() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
        update_game();

        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        loops++;
    }

    interpolation = float( GetTickCount() + SKIP_TICKS - next_game_tick )
                    / float( SKIP_TICKS );
    display_game( interpolation );
}

  // GetTickCount() returns the current number of milliseconds
// that have elapsed since the system was started
```

I have used System.currentTimeMillis() in place of GetTickCount() hoping that it would do the trick.

But I keep getting very strange results with my code:
Does anybody knows how to implement this Game loop in java?

Here is my non working example: (I keep getting large numbers for interpolation)

```
private final int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
private final int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
private final int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 5;

private double nextGameTick =  System.currentTimeMillis() ;

private int loops;
private float interpolation;

private boolean isGameRunning = true;

public GameLoop(){

while( isGameRunning ) {

    loops = 0;
    while(  System.currentTimeMillis() > nextGameTick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
        //  update_game();

        nextGameTick += SKIP_TICKS;
        loops++;
    }

    interpolation = (float)(  System.currentTimeMillis() + SKIP_TICKS - nextGameTick )/ (float)( SKIP_TICKS );
    //display_game( interpolation );
    view.display(interpolation);
}
```

}

I draw a ball at the location using the formula from the website but the ball just keeps spazzing out back and forth

view_position = position + (speed * interpolation)

I add the rest of my code so its less confusing:
(although i have a problem even before i hit this code because the interpolation number is huge when i run the debugger and it should be a fraction) 
This is my View Class which paints the ball:

```
public class View extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2744215808270823059L;

    Ball myBall = new Ball();



    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        paintBall(g);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(interpolation), 20, 20);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(myBall.getLocation()), 20, 50);
    }

    private void paintBall(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(myBall.getLocation().x, myBall.getLocation().y, myBall.getDiameter(), myBall.getDiameter() );

    }
    private float interpolation;
    public void display(float interpolation){
        Point location = new Point();
        this.interpolation = interpolation;

        location.x =  myBall.getLocation().x + (int)(myBall.getSpeedX() * interpolation);
        location.y =  myBall.getLocation().y + (int)(myBall.getSpeedY() * interpolation);
        myBall.setLocation(location);

        repaint();
    }



}
```

And my ball class:

```
public class Ball {
    private Point location = new Point();
    private int diameter;


    private double speed;
    private double speedX;
    private double speedY;

    private double angle; 

    Ball(){
        this(new Point(0, 10));
    }

    Ball(Point location){
        this(10, 3, 60, location);
    }

    Ball(int diameter, double speed, double angleDeg, Point location ){
        this.speed = speed;
        setAngleDeg(angleDeg);
        setDiameter(diameter);
        setLocation(location);
    }
    //Getters and Setters


    public double getAngleRad() {
        return angle;
    }
    public void setAngleRad(double angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
        speedX = Math.cos(angle)*speed;
        speedY = Math.sin(angle)*speed;
    }

    public double getAngleDeg() {
        return angle*180/Math.PI;
    }
    public void setAngleDeg(double angle) {
        this.angle = angle * Math.PI/180;
        speedX = Math.cos(angle)*speed;
        speedY = Math.sin(angle)*speed;
    }

    public double getSpeedX() { 
        return speedX;
    }
    public void setSpeedX(double speedX) {
        this.speedX = speedX;
    }

    public double getSpeedY() {
        return speedY;
    }
    public void setSpeedY(double speedY) {
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }
    public void setDiameter(int diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }
    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
        speedX = Math.cos(angle)*speed;
        speedY = Math.sin(angle)*speed;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a busy wait in a game loop is bad practice, I'd recommend using a different strategy, like waiting for a display refresh to render the next frame. Most game frameworks include their own game loop logic, and I highly recommend looking into one of those.

The problem looks like you're feeding the time difference into view_position rather than adding it to the time to get the actual time. So the position of the ball is based on the jitter you get between frame times rather than the time itself.

Please try out a game framework before you think of reinventing the wheel with your own; it's a lot more fun working on the game logic rather than debugging the lower level stuff. Come back to this when you're more experienced and if you need it for performance.

Comment: this is not my game loop, its taken directly out of the website that describes how to design a good game loop. Im just trying to implement it in java. I doubt its the problem with nextGameTick incrementation since its taken out of the original website. (which i linked in my question) http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Comment: Also this loop doesnt use wait inside of it... Its designed specifically to be efficient and maximize frames per second output while updating game on a constant interval.

Comment: Sorry, misread the code. Edited with what I think is the reason. And no, this NOT a good game loop. You're using 100% CPU all the time because it doesn't cap the FPS at all. If you want to write a game, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: This kind of game loop was common twenty years ago, when you needed every CPU cycle you could get. The later parts of the document you linked to talk about how this is a disadvantage when you have a lot of updates per frame; this is a big disadvantage that you can't ignore on modern hardware. I know it sounds like an inefficient approach, using a game framework, and it feels like you're losing control over your game by letting someone else's code do all the lower-level stuff, but it really is the way to go.

Comment: i  might export this application on android. I read the advantages and disadvantages of some loops I just happened to like this one. (and the article is from 2009) I know working with a game engine is a good idea and i've done it in the past, yet its not a possibility for me this time around because im doing this project to practice design patterns.

Comment: Please don't use poor design patterns. Android prefers you use their rendering callbacks that they provide with their views rather than eat up the battery; power consumption is a major reason NOT to use this type of loop.